# Appending a Variable Number of Characters to a String based on the Current Length of the String

Tags: string, vba, excel, textbox

I have a list of Names, Dates, and Titles that I am trying to output to a textbox.   I am looking to have the format of the output have the following "Columns":

Name | Date | Title | Index Number

Since this is just a textbox, I have to use tabs [chr(9)] to maintain the spacing of the "Columns" of this table.  However, since people have different length names, I need to be able to enter different numbers of tabs so that each "column" lines up correctly.  (The issue is only between Name and Date, the other "columns" are spaced correctly)

I have tried the following code, which assumes (very possibly incorrectly) that tab = 7 spaces (I have tried other numbers).  It attempts to line the dates up with the inital Date header title, which is 4 tabs from the left edge.  As a note on my Notation, I replaced the complicated paths to the Textbox and Names with the bracketed [Text Box] and [Name] for simplicity.  The following runs in a loop:

```
[Text Box].Text = "Name" & Chr(9) & Chr(9) & Chr(9) & Chr(9) & "Date" & Chr(9) & "Reason" & Chr(9) & "Index#" & Chr(10)

[[Begin Loop]]

[Text Box].Text = [Text Box].Text & [Name]

If Len([Name]) >= 0 And Len([Name]) < 7 Then
    [Text Box].Text = [Text Box].Text & Chr(9) & Chr(9) & Chr(9) & Chr(9)
ElseIf Len([Name])>= 7 And Len([Name]) < 14 Then
    [Text Box].Text = [Text Box].Text & Chr(9) & Chr(9) & Chr(9)
ElseIf Len([Name]) >= 14 And Len([Name]) < 21 Then
    [Text Box].Text = [Text Box].Text & Chr(9) & Chr(9)
ElseIf Len([Name]) >= 21 And Len([Name]) < 28 Then
    [Text Box].Text = [Text Box].Text & Chr(9)
End If

NOTE: I found that names that were an exact multiple of 7 were one tab too short, thus I added:

If Len([Name]) = 7 Or Len([Name]) = 14 Or Len([Name]) = 21 Then
    [Text Box].Text = [Text Box].Text & Chr(9)
End If

[[End Loop]]
```

The majority of the 100+ lines in the textbox are lined up correctly, however it appears that some names (not all) that have len = 14 have an extra tab.  When I remove the code that adds an extra tab for multiples of 7, some (not all) of the of the names with len = 14 are not sufficiently tabbed.

Does anyone have a solution to this?  Or another way I can represent this data (i.e. not a textbox)?

Comment: You can use a fixed-width font such as Courier for your textbox (as suggested by @NickSlash) and just pad with spaces instead of using tabs.  Easier to set up, but fixed-width fonts aren't generally very nice-looking...

Comment: Re-read your question, "is there another way?" yes! you can use a listbox as they support columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your doing it purely for visual alignment and don't need to be able to copy+paste the content into excel or something (as CSV etc) then what you're doing is almost right.

You will need to do two passes, the first pass determines the max length of each of your columns, the second pass writes it out using the information from the first to get the alignment correct.

Unless your using a fixed width font it might be slightly more challenging as it might use width instead of character count to determine how tabs move about. (not 100% sure about this)

**Update**

I had a go at making something that will convert a worksheet to a space aligned string that might do what you want :)

```
Const TABSIZE = 3

Public Function Main2(Optional ByVal SheetName As String = "Sheet1") As String
Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)
Dim Data As Variant
Dim Index, Row, Column As Long
Dim Max() As Integer
Data = Sheet.UsedRange.Value2
ReDim Max(LBound(Data, 2) To UBound(Data, 2))
' configure the Max() array with default values
For Index = LBound(Max) To UBound(Max)
    Max(Index) = 0
Next Index
' populate the Max() array with the maximum width
For Index = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
    For Column = LBound(Data, 2) To UBound(Data, 2)
        If Len(Data(Index, Column)) > Max(Column) Then
            Max(Column) = Len(Data(Index, Column))
        End If
    Next Column
Next Index
' add the tabsize to the max (add a gap between columns)
' note: the loop below is not required, has been rolled into the output loop
'For Index = LBound(Max) To UBound(Max)
'    Max(Index) = Max(Index) + TABSIZE
'Next Index
' output the data!
For Row = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
    For Column = LBound(Data, 2) To UBound(Data, 2)
        'Result = Result & Pad(Data(Row, Column), Max(Column))
        Result = Result & Pad(Data(Row, Column), Max(Column) + TABSIZE)
    Next Column
    Result = Result & vbCrLf
Next Row
' return it
Main2 = Result
End Function

' pad text to length with spaces
Public Function Pad(ByVal Text As String, ByVal Length As Long) As String
Pad = Text & Space(Length - Len(Text))
End Function
```

Comment: I decided to just use a fixed with font and use more or less my same code above.  If I run into problems in the future, though @NickSlash's answer will be the solution.